# GLSL: Can't get uniforms location

Tags: opengl, glsl

My problem is fact that I can't get some uniforms location, when location of others I get without problems.

For example I have in VS uniforms called "MVP" and "Model" and I have "MVP" location without problems, but I don't have "Model" location which I use symmetrically.
In the same manner I can't get location of fields from Light structure in FS.

Its code passing data into shader:

```
bool Shader::SetShaderParameters(mat4 MVPMatrix,mat4 Model,GLint textureUnit)
{
  GLuint matrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID,"MVP");
  if(matrixLocation==-1)
    return false;
  glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation,1,GL_FALSE,&MVPMatrix[0][0]);
  GLuint modelLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID,"Model");
  if(modelLocation==-1)
    return false;
  glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLocation,1,GL_FALSE,&Model[0][0]);
  return true;
}

bool Shader::SetShaderLights(vec3 lightColor,vec3 ambientIntensity,vec3 direction,vec3 diffuseIntensity)
{
    GLuint lightColorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID,"light.lightColor");
    if(lightColorLocation==-1)
        return false;
    glUniform3fv(lightColorLocation,1,&lightColor[0]);
    GLuint ambientIntensityLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID,"light.ambientIntensity");
    if(ambientIntensityLocation==-1)
        return false;
    glUniform3fv(ambientIntensityLocation,1,&ambientIntensity[0]);
    GLuint directionLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID,"light.direction");
    if(directionLocation==-1)
        return false;
    glUniform3fv(directionLocation,1,&direction[0]);
    GLuint diffuseIntensityLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programID,"light.diffuseIntensity");
    if(diffuseIntensityLocation==-1)
        return false;
    glUniform3fv(diffuseIntensityLocation,1,&diffuseIntensity[0]);
    return true;
}
```

It's code of shaders:

VS:

```
#version 440 core

layout(location=0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec2 vertexUV;
layout(location=2) in vec3 normal;

out vec2 uv;
out vec3 norm;

uniform mat4 Model;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = MVP*vec4(vertexPosition,1.0);
  uv = vertexUV;
  norm = (Model*vec4(normal,0.0)).xyz;
}
```

FS:

```
#version 440 core

struct Light
{
  vec3 lightColor;
  vec3 ambientIntensity;
  vec3 direction;
  vec3 diffuseIntensity;
};

in vec2 uv;
in vec3 norm;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D texSamp;
uniform Light light;

void main()
{
  color = texture(texSamp,uv).rgb*light.ambientIntensity;
}
```

What can be problem in various behaviours while getting location of uniforms? Maybe I use bad version of shaders or it's somelike optimisations of data in shaders. I was debugging my solution and I'm pretty sure that shader program IDs are correct.

[EDIT]:
When I try to use norm in FS nothing changes, and after glGetUniformLocation() which can't get location I got zero error code.

Comment: Have you checked for GL errors in the middle of the calls?

Comment: Try using the value of `norm` in the fragment shader. `Model` may be removed from the shader program if its value does not contribute to the end result.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to optimize away any unused uniforms, which is why you get this error.

You can safely ignore this. If the uniform isn't found, `glGetUniformLocation` returns -1. From the OpenGL 4.3 specs, section 7.6.1:

> If the value of location is -1, the Uniform* commands will silently
>   ignore the data passed in, and the current uniform values will not be
>   changed.

Comment: Actually, it is the ***linker*** that removes unused uniforms (they are a program state, and the compiler only deals with shaders). It is not necessarily as an optimization, but just a consequence of how linking works. If something is unused to generate a program output it generates no code path through the final linked program, so inactive uniforms and attributes generally do not appear. Seaparate Shader Objects changes this behavior a little bit, since each stage can be its own separate program (the variable only has to be used in the *current* stage to be considered active).

Comment: If you want to quote part of the spec. that actually explains what is going on, I would suggest the first paragraph of section ***7.6 Uniform Variable***: *"Shaders can declare named uniform variables, as described in the OpenGL Shading Language Speciﬁcation. A uniform is considered an active uniform if the compiler and linker determine that the uniform will actually be accessed when the executable code is executed. In cases where the compiler and linker cannot make a conclusive determination, the uniform will be considered active."*

Comment: Then you can explain that `glGetUniformLocation (...)` returns the location of an ***active*** uniform or **-1** if no uniform by that name is active. But as it stands right now, this answer does not really explain what is actually happening.

Answer (score 6):

This is an extension to [Andreas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24242830/1677912).

In my case, when I put `glGetUniformLocation` or `glUniform*` before `glUseProgram`, I got `-1`; however, when I put those two after `glUseProgram`, I can get the correct uniform location.

( My version is `OpenGL 3.3, GLSL 3.30`)