# Shader uniform either improperly optimised away or not being found

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm finally making the push to learn how to write shaders, and I have a fairly decent grasp of how they work. Problem is, I cannot retrieve the uniform location for a struct uniform. Now I know that you have to query the location of each individual inner member, which I'm doing, and I also know that if GL determines that a uniform doesn't affect the final output, it gets optimised away (which is honestly not a bad thing in the slightest).

The problem is, it's not finding a uniform which IS being used to affect the output of the fragment shader.

In my shader class, I have a function called 'GetAndStoreUniformLocation' (I like to be descriptive with the names - make sure it's clear what the function does)! This function just grabs the location of the given uniform name and shoves it into a map, so I don't have to keep querying OpenGL for the location every frame (I'm not sure how good of an optimisation this may or may not be... it's fairly experimental at this stage). This function works fine for all of the uniforms which are comprised of standard types.

#### The question (TL;DR):

**Why can't I retrieve the locations of the 'material' uniform's members from the shader? It shouldn't be being optimised away, and I'm passing "material.*"  (where * is the member name) to glGetUniformLocation().**

I feel like I'm probably missing something blatantly obvious, but I have searched around on the OpenGL documentation and on other people's posts of similar questions on here and, so far nothing has provided anything useful, only the suggestion of optimisation removing the uniform, but, I doubt that's the case since it is being used in the output.

I have tried directly calling glGetUniformLocation() after loading, compiling and linking the shader, for the matrix uniforms (success) and the material.* uniforms (failure).

#### Code

After loading the shader, I activate it so I can access the uniform locations, and call:

```cpp
v_primaryShader.GetAndStoreUniformLocation("material.ambient");
v_primaryShader.GetAndStoreUniformLocation("material.diffuse");
v_primaryShader.GetAndStoreUniformLocation("material.specular");
```

Shader::GetAndStoreUniformLocation(const GLchar* uniformName)

```cpp
void Shader::GetAndStoreUniformLocation(const GLchar* uniformName)
{
    GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(this->v_programID, uniformName);
    if (location != -1)
    {
        v_uniformLocations.insert(std::pair<const GLchar*, GLint>(uniformName, location));
        Debug::LogDebug("Uniform stored for shader '" + v_name + "': name: '" + std::string(uniformName) + "', location: '" + std::to_string(location) + "'");
        return;
    }

    ThrowException("Shader>GetAndStoreUniformLocation: Could not find uniform '" + std::string(uniformName) + "' in shader '" + this->v_name + "'.");
}
```

Shader::Debug(void)

```cpp
void Shader::Debug(void) const
{
    GLint i;
    GLint count;
    GLint size;
    GLenum type;
    const GLsizei bufSize = 25;
    GLchar name[bufSize];
    GLsizei length;

    Debug::LogDebug("Debugging shader '" + this->v_name + "':");
    glGetProgramiv(this->v_programID, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &count);
    Debug::LogDebug("  - Attributes (" + std::to_string(count) + " in total; numbers do not correspond to locations!): ");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        glGetActiveAttrib(this->v_programID, (GLuint)i, bufSize, &length, &size, &type, name);
        int location = glGetAttribLocation(this->v_programID, name);
        Debug::LogDebug("    - Attribute " + std::to_string(i) + " = name: '" + name + "', location: " + std::to_string(location) + ", type: " + TypeToString(type));
    }
    glGetProgramiv(this->v_programID, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, &count);
    Debug::LogDebug("  - Uniforms (" + std::to_string(count) + " in total; numbers do not correspond to locations!): ");
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        glGetActiveUniform(this->v_programID, (GLuint)i, bufSize, &length, &size, &type, name);
        int location = glGetUniformLocation(this->v_programID, name);
        Debug::LogDebug("    - Uniform " + std::to_string(i) + " = name: '" + name + "', location: " + std::to_string(location) + ", type: " + TypeToString(type));
    }
}
```

Fragment shader (GLSL):

```c
#version 440

struct Material
{
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
//sampler2D diffuse_texture;
//sampler2D specular_texture;
};

in vec3 pass_position;
in vec3 pass_normal;
in vec2 pass_uv;

uniform Material material;
uniform sampler2D texture0; // TODO: remove later
uniform vec3 light_position;
uniform vec3 camera_position;

out vec4 result;

void main(void)
{
    // Ambient light
    vec3 _ambient_final = material.ambient;

    // Diffuse light
    vec3 _position_to_light_directional_vector = normalize(light_position - pass_position);
    float _diffuse_dot_product = clamp(dot(_position_to_light_directional_vector, pass_normal), 0, 1);
    vec3 _diffuse_final = material.diffuse * _diffuse_dot_product;

    // Specular light
    vec3 _light_to_position_directional_vector = normalize(light_position - pass_position);
    vec3 _reflect_directional_vector = normalize(reflect(_light_to_position_directional_vector, normalize(pass_normal)));
    vec3 _position_to_view_directional_vector = normalize(pass_position - camera_position);
    float _specular_constant = pow(max(dot(_position_to_view_directional_vector, _reflect_directional_vector), 0), 70); // final number = smoothness
    vec3 _specular_final = material.specular * _specular_constant;

    // Attenuation (todo)

    // Final light (todo)

    result = texture(texture0, pass_uv) * (vec4(_ambient_final, 1.F) + vec4(_diffuse_final, 1.F) + vec4(_specular_final, 1.F));
}
```

#### Result (the error)

The Shader class also has a Debug() function which prints all the attributes and uniforms. The output I get is:

```
(call to v_primaryShader.Debug() )
[    DEBUG ] Debugging shader 'primary':
[    DEBUG ]   - Attributes (3 in total; numbers do not correspond to locations!):
[    DEBUG ]     - Attribute 0 = name: 'vertex_normal', location: 1, type: vec3
[    DEBUG ]     - Attribute 1 = name: 'vertex_position', location: 0, type: vec3
[    DEBUG ]     - Attribute 2 = name: 'vertex_uv', location: 2, type: vec2
[    DEBUG ]   - Uniforms (6 in total; numbers do not correspond to locations!):
[    DEBUG ]     - Uniform 0 = name: 'camera_position', location: 0, type: vec3
[    DEBUG ]     - Uniform 1 = name: 'light_position', location: 1, type: vec3
[    DEBUG ]     - Uniform 2 = name: 'model_matrix', location: 2, type: mat4
[    DEBUG ]     - Uniform 3 = name: 'projection_matrix', location: 3, type: mat4
[    DEBUG ]     - Uniform 4 = name: 'texture0', location: 4, type: sampler2D
[    DEBUG ]     - Uniform 5 = name: 'view_matrix', location: 5, type: mat4
(calls to v_primaryShader.GetAndStoreUniformLocation() )
[    DEBUG ] Uniform stored for shader 'primary': name: 'model_matrix', location: '2'
[    DEBUG ] Uniform stored for shader 'primary': name: 'view_matrix', location: '5'
[    DEBUG ] Uniform stored for shader 'primary': name: 'projection_matrix', location: '3'
[    DEBUG ] Uniform stored for shader 'primary': name: 'light_position', location: '1'
[    DEBUG ] Uniform stored for shader 'primary': name: 'camera_position', location: '0'
[ CRITICAL ] Exception during phase 'LOAD'
[ CRITICAL ] Shader>GetAndStoreUniformLocation: Could not find uniform 'material.ambient' in shader 'primary'.
```

, so it's definitely getting all the other uniforms just fine. But 'material' is nowhere to be seen, yet, as you can see by the shader code, the inner members of the 'Material' struct are being used for lighting, which is used in the final output for the colour. And yes, I'm fully aware the code is probably not right, or optimised... but while I'm laying down boilerplate I just need to slap a bunch of stuff in there to get it working on a rudimentary level. Lighting has been working up until making the struct (before, I was just using hard-coded values)

Comment: The names of the uniforms seems to be correct. You can introspect the program. Use `n = glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS)` and `for(i=0; i<n; ++i) glGetActiveUniform(program, i, ... )` to get all the active uniforms. See [`glGetActiveUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetActiveUniform.xhtml) respectively [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml).

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention, that's what my Shader Debug() function does (the first set of outputs in the console log)

Comment: I suppose you call `glUseProgram` before `GetAndStoreUniformLocation` right?

Comment: @Ripi2 Is not necessary that the program is the currently installed program, to query the resource index of an active program resource. (it woulfd be necessary if you want to change the value of a uniform by `glUnifrom*`).

Comment: Are you very sure that you've compiled that fragment shader? Do you mistakenly read another file with an earlier state?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yeah. But see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36416867/3871028)

Comment: @Ripi2 I see. But that' probably a driver bug and not something what is specified int the standard. By the way I don't trust in this answer and I never heard about this behavior.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Agreed. Probably a bug in the driver, whose workaround is to call `glUseProgram`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I slept. Yes, @Ripi2 I am calling `glUseProgram` right after loading the shader and compiling & linking it. And yes, both the fragment and vertex shaders are loaded (vertex first, not that I think that matters), then they're both compiled, linked to the program and then the individual shader objects are deleted since they're no longer needed. Currently this is the only shader I have, and there are no other shader source files for it to mistakenly read.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that the IDE had removed the batch file which copies the assets (shaders, textures etc) to the build directory, and there was no indication that this had happened, nor any real reason for it to. I've put the file back and now it works. *I probably should have actually checked the shader file in the build directory* to make sure it was up-to-date, but that didn't come to mind (it definitely should have, if I was smarter), but instead in my confusion and frustration I was looking for a mistake in the code.

Definitely an unexpected result, but I'm glad that this means the code/drivers aren't faulty.